# Knockout multiple dynamic text boxes with one observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, local-storage, observable

I am trying to save the data from the text-boxes to the localStorage using knockout JS! However I am new and not able to figure out this particular scenario. The field has same observable name! Please find my code below.

HTML Code:

```
<form data-bind="foreach: trialData">
    <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="textInput: myData"><br>
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
var dataModel = {
    myData: ko.observable('new'),

    dataTemplate: function (myData) {
        var self = this;
        self.myData = ko.observable(myData);
    }
};

dataModel.collectedNotes = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.trialData = ko.observableArray([]);
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        self.trialData.push (new dataModel.dataTemplate());
    }
};
dataModel.collectedNotes();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

Traget: The data entered inside the text-boxes should be available in localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Handler function to read the data from the Textboxes and save it to the `localstorage.` **You need to reference the Data which is bound to the click event, which can be accessed using the *first* parameter**. Knockout passes the data and event information as 2 arguments to the `click` handler function. So, you can add the event handler to your viewModel using the click binding and then *unwrap* the value and save it to localStorage.

```
saveToLocalStorage : function(data){
         var datatoStore = JSON.stringify(data.trialData().map(x=>x.myData()));
         console.log(datatoStore);
         localStorage.setItem("TextBoxValue", datatoStore);

    }
```

**Complete Code:** Please note since this is a sandboxed environment (Running this js Snippet on StackOverflow), `localStorage` wouldn't work, but it should work in your code. I have added a line in console to get the value to Store.

```js
var dataModel = {
    myData: ko.observable('new'),

    dataTemplate: function (myData) {
        var self = this;
        self.myData = ko.observable(myData);
    },
    
    saveToLocalStorage : function(data){
         var datatoStore = JSON.stringify(data.trialData().map(x=>x.myData()));
         console.log(datatoStore);
         localStorage.setItem("TextBoxValue", datatoStore);
         
    }
};

dataModel.collectedNotes = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.trialData = ko.observableArray([]);
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        self.trialData.push (new dataModel.dataTemplate());
    }
};
dataModel.collectedNotes();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="foreach: trialData">
    <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="textInput: myData"><br>
</form>
<button data-bind="click:saveToLocalStorage">Save To local storage</button>
```

Comment: Can the same be achieved using Knockout Subscribe method. Is it possible to eradicate a click function!

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: I have been trying to get the value back into the input box. Unfortunately I am not able to. Is there a way I can "localStorage.getItem" all the value back to the input field. Please help.

Comment: post your code, what is not working? You need to use the `localStorage.getitem` method and then use `JSON.parse` method to convert the string into a JSON.

Comment: I am able to Get and Set a variable from localStorage. However when tried with multiple Input boxes, I am bit confused on how to Get and Set the data in localStorage. (All the Input fields are dynamically generated; for example purpose I have entered three input fields)

Comment: This is working great. I just added one small condition in addition to your code. As It was throwing an error initially, when there was no saved array item in localStorage. https://jsfiddle.net/Raavan/5mhofzoa/ Thanks a lot @Agalo